# How to save multiple results in the array with for loop php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm working with a CSV file. when the user uploads the file. I parse the CSV then select the data from the array that I need. after that, I'm running a `for loop` to validate that data and saving the results in the array. but the problem is when I print the results array there's only result for 1 email and there are 4 emails. any suggestions?

```
$results = [];
$valid_emails = 0;
$invalid_emails = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $csv_array['row_count']; $i++) {
  $email = $csv_array['data'][$i][$email_column];

  $result = validate_email($email);
  $results['Email'] = $email;

  if ($result) {            
    $results['Result'] = 'valid';
    $valid_emails++;
  } else {
    $results['Result'] = 'invalid';
    $invalid_emails++;
  }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre><br>';

echo $valid_emails . '<br>';
echo $invalid_emails . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding results every time in your loop, try this

```
$results = [];
$valid_emails = 0;
$invalid_emails = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $csv_array['row_count']; $i++) {
  $email = $csv_array['data'][$i][$email_column];
$rowResult=[];
  $result = validate_email($email);
$rowResult['Email'] = $email;


  if ($result) {            
    $rowResult['Result'] = 'valid';
    $valid_emails++;
  } else {
    $rowResult['Result'] = 'invalid';
    $invalid_emails++;
  }
$results[]=$rowResult;

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre><br>';

echo $valid_emails . '<br>';
echo $invalid_emails . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$results[]` to add one or more elements :

```php
$results        = [];
$valid_emails   = 0;
$invalid_emails = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $csv_array['row_count']; $i++) {
    $email = $csv_array['data'][$i][$email_column];

    $result       = validate_email($email);
    $res['Email'] = $email;

    if ($result) {
        $res['Result'] = 'valid';
        $valid_emails++;
    } else {
        $res['Result'] = 'invalid';
        $invalid_emails++;
    }

    $results[] = $res;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre><br>';

echo $valid_emails . '<br>';
echo $invalid_emails . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$results` contains only the last email validation.
You should store multiple results, and not only the last ;-)

Something like :

```
  $results[$i]['Email'] = $email;

  if ($result) {            
    $results[$i]['Result'] = 'valid';
    $valid_emails++;
  } else {
    $results[$i]['Result'] = 'invalid';
    $invalid_emails++;
  }

  if ($result) {            
    $results[$i] = 'valid';
    $valid_emails++;
  } else {
    $results[$i] = 'invalid';
    $invalid_emails++;
  }
```